# SSRS repeat table header on every page

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

In 2005-8 it was easy. I'm using 2014. They managed to make it a total disaster. GOOD JOB MICROSOFT.

Ok, I'm making the simplest report:

A simple select query which retrieves data and it's shown on a table which headers repeat on every page. In SSRS 2005 it was a matter of 5 minutes. Now in SSRS 2014 it's 2 days and still no solution.

Here's the report:

[image]

As you can see I've added the simplest table and checked both the option to replicate the headers. I Intentionally left the middle column free to show you exactly that IT IS a table header and data section.

I already have tried to check the checkboxes SEPARATELY (one time the column header only, one time the row header only but it's not working.

I Even exported it to PDF and other formats but it's the same (sometime the visual studio plugin doesn't renders correctly).

How to make a simple table with repeating headers? In SSRS 2005 this was SO MUCH SIMPLE, now they've messed it up...

Any help?

Comment: Do you have a grouping on that first column?

Comment: @WEI_DBA I found the solution at microsoft forums, check it out below. They just thought it was funny hiding the option in some obscure sub menu and leave the main options there, not working.

Comment: Please keep your personal grievances to yourself when asking a question.  I, and I am sure many others, do not care how annoyed you are and it is a waste of our time to have to read about it when trying to obtain all the relevant information in your question.

Comment: @iamdave No. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking in microsoft forums I've found an answer. People at microsoft thought it was a clever move to bury the option to replicate table rows in some hidden submenu, just so a developer life is easier.

Here you go:
[image]